# How to integrate material-ui React inside Angular project?

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, angular-material, material-ui, ngreact

I have Angular project that uses [Angular material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select). Because of performance issues I decided to integrate `React` inside my project by using [ngReact directive](https://github.com/ngReact/ngReact).
So everything works properly. BTW I installed react with `bower` and not `npm`.

So now I'm trying to integrate [React Material UI](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar) to be able to use Material components like [drop-down-menu](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/dropdown-menu) inside React instead [md-select](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/select) in Angular material.

Today I compile react `jsx` files with `jsx` command, like:

```
jsx -w -x jsx app/scripts/components/  app/scripts/components/build/
```

So far so good.

React Material UI doesn't have `bower` but `npm`. So I installed `material-ui` so what next?

How can I use react components?  I need some `js` file to include it to my `index.html`.

When I try to include `node_modules/material-ui/index.js` I get an error:

> index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined

This is a `index.js` content:

```
'use strict';

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.ToolbarTitle = exports.ToolbarSeparator = exports.ToolbarGroup = exports.Toolbar = exports.Toggle = exports.TimePicker = exports.TextField = exports.TableRowColumn = exports.TableRow = exports.TableHeaderColumn = exports.TableHeader = exports.TableFooter = exports.TableBody = exports.Table = exports.Tab = exports.Tabs = exports.Snackbar = exports.Stepper = exports.StepLabel = exports.StepContent = exports.StepButton = exports.Step = exports.SvgIcon = exports.Subheader = exports.Slider = exports.SelectField = exports.RefreshIndicator = exports.RaisedButton = exports.RadioButtonGroup = exports.RadioButton = exports.Popover = exports.Paper = exports.MenuItem = exports.Menu = exports.MakeSelectable = exports.ListItem = exports.List = exports.LinearProgress = exports.IconMenu = exports.IconButton = exports.GridTile = exports.GridList = exports.FontIcon = exports.FloatingActionButton = exports.FlatButton = exports.DropDownMenu = exports.Drawer = exports.Divider = exports.Dialog = exports.DatePicker = exports.CircularProgress = exports.Checkbox = exports.CardText = exports.CardTitle = exports.CardMedia = exports.CardHeader = exports.CardActions = exports.Card = exports.Badge = exports.Avatar = exports.AutoComplete = exports.AppBar = undefined;

var _AppBar2 = require('./AppBar');

var _AppBar3 = _interopRequireDefault(_AppBar2);

// ....   


var _ToolbarTitle3 = _interopRequireDefault(_ToolbarTitle2);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

exports.AppBar = _AppBar3.default;
exports.AutoComplete = _AutoComplete3.default;
exports.Avatar = _Avatar3.default;
exports.Badge = _Badge3.default;

  //....

exports.ToolbarSeparator = _ToolbarSeparator3.default;
exports.ToolbarTitle = _ToolbarTitle3.default;
```

Did anyone solve/use this approach?

Comment: maybe helpful https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/368

Comment: It wasn't designed to be used in Angular, it's better to use material design implementations which works with it, for example, polymer: https://elements.polymer-project.org/